# Extract a value from SQL XML field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

Using MS SQL Server, I've got some data in an XML field (called *XML*), which is structured like this:

```
<Transaction01>
  <TransactionSetPurpose>Insert</TransactionSetPurpose>
  <POHeader>
    <PO_NBR>LG40016181</PO_NBR>
  </POHeader>
</Transaction01>
```

I'm trying to create a SQL query to fetch another column called SubmittedDate, along with the PO_NBR from this XML field.  Being new to XPath, I've read numerous examples and tried both **query** and **value**, but I've not been successful yet.  For example:

```
SELECT SubmittedDate, 
       XML.query('data(/POHeader/PO_NBR)') as PO_NBR
  FROM SubmitXML
```

This just gives me a empty column.  After getting a working test from Quassnoi, I worked from his XML to mine, and discovered the problem is the xmlns and xmlns:i attributes in the root node:

```
<Transaction01 xmlns="http://services.iesltd.com/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

So how do I get around that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  SubmittedDate, 
        XML.query('data(/Transaction01/POHeader/PO_NBR)') as PO_NBR
FROM    SubmitXML
```

You original `XPath`, `/POHeader/PO_NBR`, assumed that `POHeader` is the root node (which is not).

A sample query to check:

```
DECLARE @myxml XML
SET @myxml = '
<Transaction01>
  <TransactionSetPurpose>Insert</TransactionSetPurpose>
  <POHeader>
    <PO_NBR>LG40016181</PO_NBR>
  </POHeader>
</Transaction01>'

SELECT  @myxml.query('data(/Transaction01/POHeader/PO_NBR)')
```

If `Transaction01` is not always the root node (which is not a good thing), use this:

```
SELECT  SubmittedDate, 
        XML.query('data(/*/POHeader/PO_NBR)') as PO_NBR
FROM    SubmitXML
```

Generally, `XML` schema assumes that the tag names are fixed and the variable parts go to the data of the nodes and the attributes rather than into their names, like this:

```
<Transaction id='01'>
  <TransactionSetPurpose>Insert</TransactionSetPurpose>
  <POHeader>
    <PO_NBR>LG40016181</PO_NBR>
  </POHeader>
</Transaction>
```

**Update:**

You should declare the namespaces using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`:

```
DECLARE @myxml XML
SET @myxml = '
<Transaction01 xmlns="http://services.iesltd.com/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <TransactionSetPurpose>Insert</TransactionSetPurpose>
  <POHeader>
    <PO_NBR>LG40016181</PO_NBR>
  </POHeader>
</Transaction01>'

;
WITH    XMLNAMESPACES
        (
        'http://services.iesltd.com/' AS m
        )
SELECT  @myxml.query
        (
        'data(/*/m:POHeader/m:PO_NBR)'
        )
```

**Update 2:**

To sort:

```
;
WITH    XMLNAMESPACES
        (
        'http://services.iesltd.com/' AS m
        )
SELECT  SubmittedDate, 
        XML.value('(/*/m:POHeader/m:PO_NBR)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(200)') AS po_nbr
FROM    SubmitXML
ORDER BY
        po_nbr
```

Comment: Thanks, Quassnoi.  I had tried that earlier, and unfortunately it also gives me the blank column.  I've read various things that indicate that the root element should be omitted, although I've seen it done both ways.

Comment: @marc_s: `LG40016181` is hardly an int :) Your query assumes that the @op wants to return the first node instead of concatenating all of them.

Comment: @Mike: added a sample query. If the root node is called other than `Transaction01`, use another query (see the post update).

Comment: @Quassnoi: Your test script works just fine, but for some reason my own data does not.

Comment: @Mike: I assume this is a good time to post a sample of your data so that we could see why.

Comment: I've worked from your XML sample to mine, and I've posted my findings in an edited version of my question.

Comment: Ok, that's got the values appearing.  Thanks!!!  One more problem, though.  Now I need to sort and group by PO_NBR, and I'm getting the error "xml data type cannot be compared or sorted".

Comment: @Mike: cast your data into `VARCHAR` (see the post update). Note that this only selects first `PO_NBR` node. What if you have more than one?

Comment: There is only one per transaction.  Thanks again.

Comment: Your suggestion (using either **query** with a CAST or **value**) works great for SORT BY, but GROUP BY gives an error: Invalid column name 'PO_NBR'.

Comment: @Mike: enclose it into a subquery and use `GROUP BY` out of it. `GROUP BY` cannot use aliases, unlike `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid hardcoding Transaction01, you can try this:

```
SELECT  SubmittedDate,          
        XML.query('data(//POHeader/PO_NBR)') as PO_NBR 
  FROM  SubmitXML
```

E.G:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (XMLTEXT XML)

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
SELECT '<Transaction01>   <TransactionSetPurpose>Insert</TransactionSetPurpose>   <POHeader>     <PO_NBR>LG40016181</PO_NBR>   </POHeader> </Transaction01> '

SELECT XMLTEXT.query('data(//POHeader/PO_NBR)') as PO_NBR   
 FROM #TEMP
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried that earlier, but it didn't work either.

Comment: It turns out I was tripping on namespaces.  Thanks for your help!